# Boost on eclipse on windows

Tags: eclipse, boost

I am using eclipse luna on win 7.
Here is my program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    // All programs that use asio need to have at least one io_service object
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    // sets the timer to expire 5 seconds from now
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    t.wait();

    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";

    return 0;
```

}

Here is my command line code

```
g++ -I"C:\Users\Documents\Lib\boost_1_57_0\boost_1_57_0" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_libraryname -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++  -o "002_TimerSynchronously"  ./main.o
```

Error

```
C:/Users/SulfredLee/Documents/Lib/boost_1_57_0/boost_1_57_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:221: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:/Users/SulfredLee/Documents/Lib/boost_1_57_0/boost_1_57_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:/Users/SulfredLee/Documents/Lib/boost_1_57_0/boost_1_57_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
```

Anyone knows how to fix it?
Thank you very much

Reference:
[undefined reference to boost::system::system_category() when compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723793/undefined-reference-to-boostsystemsystem-category-when-compiling)
[How do I troubleshoot boost library/header inclusion via autoconf/automake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270073/how-do-i-troubleshoot-boost-library-header-inclusion-via-autoconf-automake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries should be present in the second command line when the linking takes place. Please be also careful and list the libraries after the object file.

Comment: g++ -I"C:\Users\Documents\Lib\boost_1_57_0\boost_1_57_0" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_libraryname -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"<br>
g++ -L"C:\Users\Documents\Lib\boost_1_57_0\boost_1_57_0" -o "002_TimerSynchronously"  ./main.o  <br>
This time I did this but still get the errors.

Comment: g++  -o "002_TimerSynchronously"  ./main.o  -L"C:\Users\Documents\Lib\boost_1_57_0\boost_1_57_0" -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system

Comment: Now the errors are:
g++ -L"C:\Users\Documents\Lib\boost_1_57_0\boost_1_57_0" -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -o "002_TimerSynchronously"  ./main.o   
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_filesystem
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_system

Comment: Are you possibly missing a "SulfredLee" in your boost installation path "C:\Users\SulfredLee\Documents\..."? In your post it appears to be the installation directory.